# Codeigniter Message: Cookie names must not be empty

Tags: php, codeigniter

A PHP ERROR was encountered in the mean time of the logout process. Login & logout process it still working fine! But it shows an error when i logout the system!
Severity: Warning 
Message: Cookie names must not be empty 
Filename: core/Input.php 
Line Number: 286

Here is the code of my Input.php set_cookie function:

```
function set_cookie($name = '', $value = '', $expire = '', $domain = '', $path = '/', $prefix = '', $secure = FALSE)
{
    if (is_array($name))
    {
        // always leave 'name' in last place, as the loop will break otherwise, due to $$mill
        foreach (array('value', 'expire', 'domain', 'path', 'prefix', 'secure', 'name') as $mill)
        {
            if (isset($name[$mill]))
            {
                $$mill = $name[$mill];
            }
        }
    }

    if ($prefix == '' AND config_mill('cookie_prefix') != '')
    {
        $prefix = config_mill('cookie_prefix');
    }
    if ($domain == '' AND config_mill('cookie_domain') != '')
    {
        $domain = config_mill('cookie_domain');
    }
    if ($path == '/' AND config_mill('cookie_path') != '/')
    {
        $path = config_mill('cookie_path');
    }
    if ($secure == FALSE AND config_mill('cookie_secure') != FALSE)
    {
        $secure = config_mill('cookie_secure');
    }

    if ( ! is_numeric($expire))
    {
        $expire = time() - 86500;
    }
    else
    {
        $expire = ($expire > 0) ? time() + $expire : 0;
    }

    setcookie($prefix.$name, $value, $expire, $path, $domain, $secure);
}
```

Line Number: 286

```
setcookie($prefix.$name, $value, $expire, $path, $domain, $secure);
```

Comment: setcookie($prefix.$name, $value, $expire, $path, $domain, $secure); is called inside function?

Comment: Yes, the setcookie was called inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes :

- Only the name and value are required. To delete a cookie set it with the expiration blank.
- The expiration is set in seconds, which will be added to the current time. Do not include the time, but rather only the number of seconds from now that you wish the cookie to be valid. If the expiration is set to zero the cookie will only last as long as the browser is open.
- For site-wide cookies regardless of how your site is requested, add your URL to the domain starting with a period, like this: .your-domain.com

  ```
  $cookie = array(
  'name'   => 'demo',
    'value'  => 'Hello i m cookies which saved in this broswer',
     'expire' => '86500',
  'domain' => 'yourdomain', // in localhost this should be null
  'path'   => '/',
  'prefix' => 'myprefix_',
  'secure' => TRUE    );
  $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
  ```

**Discrete Parameters**

If you prefer, you can set the cookie by passing data using individual parameters:

```
$this->input->set_cookie($name, $value, $expire, $domain, $path, $prefix, $secure);
```